# Accessing Firebase object and map it to UI in Angular based app

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase

I am trying to access this data sample (comments) in firebase realtime database from my Nativescript Angular application to render the comments in the xml code below.

This code works fine with JSON data imported to my database but not with the auto-generated alphanumeric ids created by firebase after initiating the push() request. (If you substitute the string ids with integers the code will work fine).

**Firebase screenshot.**
[image]

**Typescript file**

```js
export class DishdetailComponent implements OnInit {
  
    dish: Dish;
    id: number;
    comment: Comment;
    errMess: string;
    avgstars: string; 
    numcomments: number; 
    favorite: boolean;  

    showComments: boolean = false;

    cardImage: View;
    commentList: View;
    cardLayout: View;

    constructor(private dishservice: DishService,
      private route: ActivatedRoute,
      private routerExtensions: RouterExtensions,
      private favoriteService: FavoriteService, 
      private vcRef: ViewContainerRef,
      private modalService: ModalDialogService, 
      private http: HttpClient,
      private page: Page, 
      @Inject('baseURL') private baseURL) { }
  
    ngOnInit() {
      this.route.params
        .pipe(switchMap((params: Params) => this.dishservice.getDish(params['id'])))
        .subscribe(dish => {
          this.dish = dish 
          this.favorite = this.favoriteService.isFavorite(this.dish.id); 
          
            //compute the average of the comments and the render the length of the array
            const commentIds  = Object.keys(this.dish.comments);
            this.numcomments =  commentIds.length;           
            let total = 0; 
            commentIds.forEach(commentId => total += this.dish.comments[commentId].rating); 
            this.avgstars = (total/this.numcomments).toFixed(2) || null;
             },
            errmess => this.errMess = <any>errmess); 
          }

        onDrawerButtonTap(): void {
            const sideDrawer = <RadSideDrawer>app.getRootView();
            sideDrawer.showDrawer();
        }

**Html template file**
```

```html
  <Label row="1" height="40" class="p-10 m-t-10 h3" text="Comments"></Label>
        <ListView id="commentList" 
        row="2"
        height="300"
        [items]="dish.comments" 
        class="list-group p-10"
        [visibility]="(showComments) ? 'visible': 'collapsed'">
            <ng-template let-comment="item">
                <StackLayout class="list-group-item">
                    <Label class="list-group-item-heading" [text]="comment.comment" textWrap="true"></Label>
                    <StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
                        <Label class="list-group-item-text" [text]="comment.rating"></Label>      
                        <Label class="list-group-item-text" text=" Stars"></Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
                    <Label class="list-group-item-text" [text]="'-- ' + comment.author + ', '"></Label>      
                    <Label class="list-group-item-text" [text]="comment.date | date"></Label>
                    </StackLayout>      
                </StackLayout>
            </ng-template>
        </ListView>
```

What am I doing wrong in my code?
I would highly appreciate your review and correction.

Comment: (If you substitute the string ids with integers the code will work fine).  then parseInt your params['id']

Comment: @upinderkumar How could you change the snippet ? I tried it and  stills the same.

Comment: actually i am not change snippet. i am just suggest you.

Comment: @upinderkumar, I meant how would, but i wrote how could. Do you mean type conversion like this :   (+params['id']) ?

Comment: @upinderkumar this gives rise to the following error: "Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.ts(2345)"

Comment: i think you have to make custom id for your records.